# Adding an SWT Button to a ButtonGroup

Tags: java, swt

Using SWT, I want to group some buttons by using the `group.add(button);` method to add them to a `ButtonGroup`.

```
  Button cb3 = new Button(c3, SWT.RADIO);
  cb3.setSize(20, 20);
  cb3.setLocation(110, 3);

  ButtonGroup radios = new ButtonGroup();
  radios.add(cb3);
```

But I get this error:

- The method add(AbstractButton) in the type ButtonGroup is not applicable for the arguments ().

Comment: zibil, I noticed that your original code said `radios.add()` then you edited it to be `radios.add(cb3)`.  The original code would have caused this error, while your edited code should have a different error.

Comment: Sorry about it.I've noticed it late.True code is radios.add(cb3),last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a Swing class (ButtonGroup) with SWT. In SWT, you could create the buttons in a Composite to form a group. Check out the button snippets on http://eclipse.org/swt/snippets

Comment: Actually, I need 3 radio button but each of them are in different Composite group,already.And,they are in different locations in screen.So the thing I try to do single selection among them.